# How to get access to methods by this?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have component class A:

```
class A {
    public do() {
    }

    public go() {
       this.set<A>(this);
    }
}
```

And class `B` that contains method `set()`:

```
class B {
    public set<T>(e: T) {
        e.do(); // Why I can not get access to method `do()`?
    }
}
```

Why I can not get access to method `do()`?

Comment: What if `e` isn't an instance of `A`?

Comment: `e` can be instance any of class

Comment: There lies the issue - if `e` can be any class, then you can only call methods on it that can be called on any class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`set<T>(e: T)` is generic. It knows nothing about what `T` can be passed in. You can change the generic constraint to `T extends A` or `T extends SomethingThatHasDo` then it will know about the `do` method. For example:

```
class B {
    public set<T extends A>(e: T) {
        e.do(); // Why I can not get access to method `do()`?
    }
}
```

I would suggest [reading the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) on what generics can and cannot do.

Comment: But I pass concrete generic type of class A, why it can not aware?

Comment: Can you extend your answer, where to write `T extends A`?

Comment: Problem is that It can be not only class `A` - ANY

Comment: @OPV correct. typescript is enforcing `set` to know what `e` has on it. what do you expect if you pass a string to `set`?

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is preventing you from calling `.do()` because the type of `e` could be any type. For example, doing `new B().set(5);` would cause a runtime error because `5.do()` doesn't exist.

If you want to accept any type for `e`, then you should check if the passed in object is of type `A` before calling `.do()`:

```
class B {
    // do you really need to use a type parameter here?
    // Maybe just make it unknown as shown:
    set(e: unknown) {
        if (e instanceof A)
            e.do(); // ok
    }
}
```

Or alternatively check if it's an object with a `do` method:

```
class B {
    set(e: unknown) {
        if (hasDo(e))
            e.do(); // ok
    }
}

function hasDo(obj: any): obj is { do(): void; } {
    return typeof obj.do === "function";
}
```

Or restrict the objects passed in to be of type `A` by only accepting parameters of type `A`:

```
class B {
    set(e: A) {
        e.do();
    }
}
```